# Can I change the display color of names of grouped objects in the viewport?

Tags: objects, 3d-view

After adding object names to the viewport (using `Object.show_name = True`), it looks something like this:

[image]

Ball 2 and Ball 3 are identical to Ball 1 except for the fact that they have been added to an arbitrary group. As a result, their names appear in a green color instead of the default black. **Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?** I wish to keep all names black independent of their grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can change the theme so that grouped objects are black:

[image]

In <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User Preferences > Themes > 3D view > Object Grouped*.